# Inserting parameters for different environments using $FILE

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I'm working to parameterize my API's for different environments. I'm following https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/develop/injecting-parameters/ article and using file based approach.
I created the parameters in the File and want to use these on http endpoint example below

```
<call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="$FILE:getIds">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
 Failed. org.apache.synapse.commons.resolvers.ResolverException: File Property variable could not be found
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.resolvers.FilePropertyResolver.resolve(FilePropertyResolver.java:59)
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Have you defined `getIds` in the file.properties file in <MI_HOME>/conf directory? Could you share that file as well

Comment: Thanks SanoJ. It’s working now. I forgot to add the default file path in integrator file